# onclick works but addEventListener doesn't?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, addeventlistener, eventhandler

Ok so I was creating a practice project that I saw on another website

I am used to `addEventListeners` as the default event handling function, however, in the code below; the quiz app I am creating go through the questions but do not update the score even if the answer was right. I kept debugging and console logging for almost 2 hours till I found out that the "very odd" problem was simply that I add `addEventListener` handler to the buttons where the user click on to select an answer instead of an `onclick` function.. I want to know what is actually the problem...

Please open the code panel to see the code.

The problem exactly is `on line 73` in the code.

What added more to my confusion is that when I moved the `this.currentQuestionIndex++` `on line 17` inside the if statement within the `Quiz.prototype.checkAnswer` method, it worked fine with `addEventListener`.

Need your help to understand the mystery behind this.

```js
//Creating the Quiz object
function Quiz(questions) {
  this.questions = questions;
  this.score = 0;
  this.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.grabQuestion = function() {
  return this.questions[this.currentQuestionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.checkAnswer = function(answer) {
  if(this.grabQuestion().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
    this.score++;
    console.log(this.score);
  }
  this.currentQuestionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.hasEnded = function() {
  return this.currentQuestionIndex >= this.questions.length;
}

//creating the Question object.
function Question(title,choices,answer) {
  this.title = title;
  this.choices = choices;
  this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
  return this.answer === choice;
}

//Creating the Quiz Interface(Rendering into HTML)

var quizInterface = {
  displayNext: function() {
    if(quiz.hasEnded()) {
      this.displayScore();
    }
    else {
    this.displayQuestion();
    this.displayChoices();
    this.displayProgress();
    }
  },

  displayScore: function() {
    var scoreDisplay = 'your score is ' + quiz.score;
    this.populateIdWithHTML("quiz",scoreDisplay)
  },
  displayQuestion: function() {
    this.populateIdWithHTML("question",quiz.grabQuestion().title);
  },

  displayChoices: function() {
    var choices = quiz.grabQuestion().choices;
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      this.populateIdWithHTML("choice" + i, choices[i]);
      this.checkingHandler("guess" + i, choices[i]);
    }
  },

  displayProgress: function() {
    var currentQuestionNum = quiz.currentQuestionIndex + 1;
    this.populateIdWithHTML("progress","Question " + currentQuestionNum + " of " + quiz.questions.length)
  },

  checkingHandler: function(id,checking) {
    var btn = document.getElementById(id);

    /* The addEventListener function throws an error for some reason */

      btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      quiz.checkAnswer(checking);
      quizInterface.displayNext();
      },false)

    //The onclick function works though normally though...
    /*  btn.onclick = function() {
        quiz.checkAnswer(checking);
        quizInterface.displayNext();
      }
     */
  },

  populateIdWithHTML: function(id,theHTML) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.innerHTML = theHTML;
  }
}

var questionOne = new Question('What is the whole area of Egypt?',['1MKM','2MKM'],'1MKM');
var questionTwo = new Question('What is the currency of Egypt?',['EGP','USD'],'EGP');
var questionThree = new Question('What is the capital of Egypt?',['cairo','baghdad'],'cairo');
var questionFour = new Question('What is the latest Battlefield game?',['BF4','BF1'],'BF1');
var questionFive = new Question('What is the OS of Mac laptops?',['Mac IOS','Mac OS'],'Mac OS');

var questions = [questionOne,questionTwo,questionThree,questionFour,questionFive];

var quiz = new Quiz(questions);
quizInterface.displayNext();
```

```css
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }

.srt, .form__label--hidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px; }

.panel--centered, .panel--padded--centered, [class^="btn--"] {
  text-align: center; }

[class^="progbar__"]:after, .icn--nav-toggle:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute; }

.centered, .grid {
  float: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; }

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 2.5em; }

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block; }

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0; }

[hidden],
template {
  display: none; }

a {
  background: transparent; }

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0; }

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted; }

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold; }

dfn {
  font-style: italic; }

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0; }

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000; }

small {
  font-size: 80%; }

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

sup {
  top: -0.5em; }

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em; }

img {
  border: 0; }

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden; }

figure {
  margin: 1em 40px; }

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0; }

pre {
  overflow: auto; }

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em; }

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0; }

button {
  overflow: visible; }

button,
select {
  text-transform: none; }

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer; }

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default; }

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0; }

input {
  line-height: normal; }

*
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0; }

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto; }

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box; }

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none; }

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em; }

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0; }

textarea {
  overflow: auto; }

optgroup {
  font-weight: bold; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

td,
th {
  padding: 0; }

* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  color: #797e83;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5; }

h3 {
  font-size: 1.125em; }

h4 {
  margin-top: 1.375em;
  margin-bottom: 2.57143em;
  color: #d6d7d9;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.875em; }
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    h4 {
      margin-top: 2.625em; } }

a {
  color: #656a6e;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400; }

p {
  margin: .8em 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  line-height: 1.5; }

blockquote {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.25em; }
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    blockquote {
      margin: 1.33333em 0;
      padding: 0 0 0 5%;
      border-left: 0.33333em solid #ebecec;
      font-size: 1.5em; } }

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none; }

img {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; }

input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0; }

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  transition: 0.3s; }

button {
  outline: 0; }

footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #ebecec;
  margin-top: 1.375em; }
  footer p {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 1.375em; }

.panel, .panel--centered {
  padding-top: 1.875em; }
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    .panel, .panel--centered {
      padding-bottom: 1.25em; } }

.panel--padded, .panel--padded--centered {
  padding-top: 2.125em; }
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    .panel--padded, .panel--padded--centered {
      padding-top: 5em;
      padding-bottom: 2.125em; } }

.grid {
  width: 90%; }
  [class*="grid__col--"] > .grid {
    width: 100%; }
  @media (min-width: 1100px) {
    .grid {
      max-width: 1050px; } }

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .grid__col--1 {
    width: 6.5%; }
  .grid__col--2 {
    width: 15%; }
  .grid__col--3 {
    width: 23.5%; }
  .grid__col--4 {
    width: 32%; }
  .grid__col--5 {
    width: 40.5%; }
  .grid__col--6 {
    width: 49%; }
  .grid__col--7 {
    width: 57.5%; }
  .grid__col--8 {
    width: 66%; }
  .grid__col--9 {
    width: 74.5%; }
  .grid__col--10 {
    width: 83%; }
  .grid__col--11 {
    width: 91.5%; }
  .grid__col--12 {
    width: 100%; } }

@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  [class^="grid__col--"] {
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    margin-bottom: 0.75em; } }
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  [class^="grid__col--"] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px; }
    [class^="grid__col--"] + [class^="grid__col--"] {
      margin-left: 2%; }
    [class^="grid__col--"]:last-of-type {
      float: right; } }

.theme__poly .grid [class*="grid__col"] {
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1.75%; }

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .nav__item, .nav__item--current {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0.625em; } }

.nav__item--current a, .nav__item a {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.4em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; }
  @media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav__item--current a, .nav__item a {
      border-bottom-color: #ebecec;
      padding-top: 0.77778em;
      padding-bottom: 0.77778em; } }

.nav__item--current a, .nav__item a:hover {
  color: #0b0b0b;
  border-color: #52bab3; }

h1, .headline-primary, .headline-primary--grouped {
  color: #525559;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.625em;
  line-height: 1.09524;
  margin-top: 0; }

h2, .headline-secondary, .headline-secondary--grouped {
  color: #999da1;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

.form__btn, [class^="btn--"] {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  display: block; }
  .form__btn:hover, [class^="btn--"]:hover {
    opacity: .75; }
  .form__btn:active, [class^="btn--"]:active {
    opacity: initial; }

.menu__link, .menu__link--end {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.2);
  font-size: 1.125em; }

.icn--nav-toggle, .icn--close {
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer; }

.img--wrap {
  border: 1px solid #d6d7d9;
  padding: 0.75em; }
.img--avatar {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50%; }
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    .img--avatar {
      margin-top: 1.5em; } }
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .img--hero {
    margin-bottom: 2.625em; } }

.headline-primary {
  margin-bottom: 1.66667em; }
  .headline-primary--grouped {
    margin-bottom: 0; }
.headline-secondary {
  margin-bottom: 0.91667em; }
  .headline-secondary--grouped {
    margin-top: 0.41667em;
    margin-bottom: 2.25em; }

.form__label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.625em; }
.form__input {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin-bottom: 1.11111em;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #d6d7d9;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background: #ebecec;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300; }
  .form__input:focus {
    border-color: #52bab3; }
.form__btn {
  background: #52bab3; }

.btn--default {
  background-color: #52bab3; }
.btn--success {
  background-color: #5ece7f; }
.btn--error {
  background-color: #e67478; }
.btn--warning {
  background-color: #ff784f; }
.btn--info {
  background-color: #9279c3; }

[class^="btn--"] {
  margin-bottom: 1.42857em; }
  @media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    [class^="btn--"] {
      width: 100%; } }
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    [class^="btn--"] {
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block; }
      [class^="btn--"] + [class^="btn--"] {
        margin-left: 20px; } }

.navbar {
  position: relative; }
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    .navbar {
      margin-top: 3.375em;
      margin-bottom: 0; } }

.nav {
  margin-top: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 1.875em; }
  .nav__item a {
    color: #797e83; }

.offcanvas {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.625em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #39add1;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(94, 206, 127, 0.8) 0%, #39add1 100%); }

.menu {
  margin-top: 1.25em; }
  .menu__link {
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }

.progbar {
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #d6d7d9;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2.875em; }
  .progbar__status--default {
    background-color: #52bab3; }
    .progbar__status--default:after {
      background-color: #6fc6c0; }
  .progbar__status--success {
    background-color: #5ece7f; }
    .progbar__status--success:after {
      background-color: #7dd898; }
  .progbar__status--error {
    background-color: #e67478; }
    .progbar__status--error:after {
      background-color: #ec979a; }
  .progbar__status--warning {
    background-color: #ff784f; }
    .progbar__status--warning:after {
      background-color: #ff9778; }
  .progbar__status--info {
    background-color: #9279c3; }
    .progbar__status--info:after {
      background-color: #a995d0; }

[class^="progbar__"] {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  position: relative; }
  [class^="progbar__"]:after {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    right: -10px;
    top: -8px; }

.site-logo {
  background-image: url("../img/logo.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 115px;
  height: 45px;
  display: inline-block; }

.icn--nav-toggle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 17px;
  border-top: solid 3px #797e83;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #797e83;
  position: relative; }
  .icn--nav-toggle:before {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #999da1;
    top: 4px; }
.icn--close {
  background-image: url("../img/icn-close.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  top: 4%; }

@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .is-displayed-mobile {
    display: block; }
    .is-hidden-mobile {
      display: none; } }
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .is-displayed-mobile {
    display: none; } }

@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .is-collapsed-mobile {
    visibility: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0; } }

.theme__poly .grid__col--12 {
  background-color: #DEF4E5; }

.theme__poly .grid__col--8 {
  background-color: #DCE0F2; }

.theme__poly .grid__col--7 {
  background-color: #DCF0EF; }

.theme__poly .grid__col--6 {
  background-color: #FFE3DB; }

.theme__poly .grid__col--4 {
  background-color: #F8EDD0; }

.theme__poly .grid__col--5 {
  background-color: #EAEBEC; }

.theme__poly .grid__col--2 {
  background-color: #C5E2CE; }

.theme__poly .grid__col--3 {
  background-color: #D6EEF5; }
```

```html
<head lang="en">
    <title>The Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid">
    <div id="quiz" class="centered grid__col--8">
        <h1>Quiz</h1>

        <h2 id="question" class="headline-secondary--grouped"></h2>
        <h3 id="score"></h3>

        <p id="choice0"></p>
        <button id="guess0" class="btn--default">Select Answer</button>

        <p id="choice1"></p>
        <button id="guess1" class="btn--default">Select Answer</button>

        <footer>
            <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're calling `quiz.checkAnswer()` differently. In the `addEventListener` version you left out the argument.

Comment: sorry I did that when I was trying to debug. I added the argument back and still the same error pops up..

Comment: What error? Post the problem code in the question, not the working code.

Comment: Which line is line 73? There are no line numbers in SO code.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I thought you had access to the fiddle. Search with "checkingHandler: function(id,checking) {" it is the statements within this method.

Comment: The stack snippet has the broken code commented out. So how can we use that to see what's going wrong?

Comment: @Barmar fixed now. I commented out the working code and uncommented the broken one.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the problem is. What error are you getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140119/discussion-between-ahmed-magdy-and-barmar).

Comment: @Barmar: If you click a button multiple times, there's an error about a function not being defined. The question needs reduced code and enhanced explanation.

Comment: From some simple logging `console.log(btn.onclick)`, it seems you're binding event handlers again when the button is clicked. For `onclick` this overwrites the original handler. For `addEventListener`, it doesn't since you're passing a new function every time. So the redundant handlers are throwing off the logic.

Comment: @squint thanks. is there a workaround to still use addEventListener and make it work properly?

Comment: Just add the event listener once, not every time. Or use `removeEventListener` first.

Comment: Analyze and change your logic so that the `checkingHandler` doesn't run with every click. If you were passing the same function (by reference id), it wouldn't re-bind it, but you rely on closure, so that's out of the question.

Comment: Instead of adding a closure each time, add a single event listener that uses `quiz.currentQuestionIndex` to determine the current question.

Comment: I think the *EventListener Interface* is a nice way to handle this. It joins the object state and the event handling into one. Worth researching IMO.

Comment: @squint excuse me for this but I am kinda new to the language. Would you please rewrite that piece of code to see how it shall work? I learn best by seeing examples. Appreciate your help

Comment: Yep, hang on a minute.

Comment: So you're reusing the elements that hold the quiz data, and just updating their content. That's why you don't need to rebind handlers. Your `quizInterface` methods can really be methods on `Quiz.prototype`. Because the button is associated with the quiz, you can bind the handlers once when you create the quiz. I'm still organizing a bit.

Comment: Well, this is a start: https://jsfiddle.net/623n008y/ Most of the logic is on `Quiz` since that's managing the application. Let me know if you have questions. Notice that we bind `this` (the Quiz instance) instead of a function. This is possible because of the `handleEvent` method.

Comment: ...right now every answer is a correct answer, so that clearly needs to change. This just gets the overall mechanics down.

Comment: yep. still trying to figure the logic to fix this

Comment: any luck with that yet? @squint

Comment: Oh, well there are different ways to approach it. Since the answer that corresponds to each button is stored on the page, you could get the `event.currentTarget`, which is the button clicked, and traverse over to the element that holds the corresponding answer, and pass that to the `Question` to see if it's correct. Another option would be to do it by index. The button's ID has an index number on it, so you could compare that to the index number of the correct answer in the `choices` of the current question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140127/discussion-between-ahmed-magdy-and-squint).